# Accessing Apache ActiveMQ via JMX throws Exception

Tags: exception, activemq-classic, jmx

I'm using a fresh ActiveMQ 5.8.0 installation, where I have a message in a queue called 'testing'. I also replaced the ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX line in `bin/activemq` to enable JMX:

```
ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

Then I query JMX via the following code:

```
    try {
        JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi"));
        connector.connect();
        MBeanServerConnection connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();

        ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Broker");
        BrokerViewMBean mbean = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(connection, mbeanName, BrokerViewMBean.class, true);

        System.out.println("Id:" + mbean.getBrokerId()); // here the exception will be thrown
    }
    catch (Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The Exception is thrown when accessing the mbean.

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy0.getBrokerId(Unknown Source)
    at testing.TestJmx.main(TestJmx.java:25)
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Broker
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:643)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:668)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1424)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:89)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1292)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1380)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:160)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.getAttribute(RMIConnector.java:901)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:280)
    ... 2 more
```

I checked that that port is listening, VisualVM also shows me the mbeans, ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fact that bean names have changed is documented on the 5.8.0 [release page](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-580-release.html).

So your ObjectName should be of the form:

```
    ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost");
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. Unfortunately all examples I found out there were prior 5.8 release

Comment: Tim, what would be the answer how to fix the tools broken by this - such as HermesJMS and ActiveMQBrowser which I can't get to work with 5.8.0 ??

Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Works, but I needed to use this ObjectName:  `org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Broker`

Answer (score 1):

Excellent answer. Here you have an example of use: [API Docs](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/activemq/web/BrokerFacadeSupport.html)

There is also something important that changes from 5.7 to 5.8. The default URL for JMX services goes from:

```
service:jmx:rmi://localhost/jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

to:

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

Answer (score 0):

Lovely question and answer too, I was having a hard time configuring JMX. ActiveMQ docs isn't up-to-date in this regard. Eg : http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html doesn't say that from 5.8.0 onwards "SUNJMX" becomes "ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START".

The config provided by OP , ie :
ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"

, and the corresponding code is the one that really worked for me. Thanks ! ( I am using ActiveMQ 5.8)