# How can one make HermesJMS and ActiveMQBrowser work with the latest Apache ActiveMQ 5.8

Tags: activemq-classic

5.8 has renamed the objects

as http://activemq.apache.org/58-migration-guide.html

"Type=Broker" => "type=Broker"

which results in exception, described here in the question:

[Accessing Apache ActiveMQ via JMX throws Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837853/accessing-apache-activemq-via-jmx-throws-exception/16582971#16582971)

now...
the answer given there 
is basically to "change your code" 
BUT 
my question and need is how 
to make exiting JMS/JMX tools such as HermesJMS and ActiveMQBrowser work with ActiveMQ 5.8

is there any updated "plugins"/"provider" jars available for HermesJMS
or is there any workaround trick or reasonably sensible "hack"??

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

https://github.com/paoloantinori/HermesJMS

Verified working on both ActiveMQ 5.8 and 5.9.

No need to build, just have a look at the README and download the .jar you have to overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

Both projects are open source.

You specifically ask for Hermes JMS. There is a CVS repo at Source Forge and a "reasonable hack" would probably apply the [mapping table](http://activemq.apache.org/58-migration-guide.html) you refer to in [This file](http://sourceforge.net/p/hermesjms/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/HermesJMS/src/java/hermes/ext/activemq/ActiveMQAdmin.java#l296)

Haven't tested, but shouldn't be much more and a few minutes of work.

Someone will probably do it sooner or later. Note that just changing the code will probably make that version incompatible with older AMQ versions. So a better way would be to write a ActiveMQ 5.8 plugin side by side with the old one.

Not sure about ActiveMQBrowser. Shouldn't be much different approach though

Comment: thanks Petter! makes sense... also in case of HermesJMS, where the "providers"/"plugins" are being specified individually and separately from the main tool (HermesJMS itself) makes lot of sense to have a seperate ones for 5.8 along side the "legacy" ones (e.g., activemq-core-5.2.0.jar)