# Accessing Apache ActiveMQ via JMX throws Exception Broker Not Found 5.10

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jmx

I'm using a fresh ActiveMQ 5.10.0 installation, where I have a message in a queue called 'testing'. I also replaced the ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX line in bin/activemq to enable JMX:

```
ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"

JMXServiceURL url1 = new 
JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://10.222.222.222:1099/jmxrmi");
    JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url1);
    MBeanServerConnection conn = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection( );
    ObjectName activeMQ = new 
 ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,BrokerName=TOM");

    System.out.println(newProxyInstance(conn, activeMQ, BrokerViewMBean.class, true).toString( ));
    Set<ObjectName> brokers = conn.queryNames(activeMQ, null);
                      if (brokers.size() == 0) {
                                    throw new IOException("No broker could be found in the JMX.");
                         }
```

The exception thrown is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No broker could be found in 
the JMX.
```

Similar to [Accessing Apache ActiveMQ via JMX throws Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837853/accessing-apache-activemq-via-jmx-throws-exception/15839294) but did not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect to activemq's jmx .
In CLI type jconsole or go to your JDK bin path and run jconsole from command line.[image]
You will see this interface. Connect to your jmx.[image]
Go here exactly and look at your object.
Copy exactly into your object name. Any! difference and you will not get your broker.

Comment: So I could 
  
  org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,BrokerName=TOM,connector=clientC
   onnectors,connectorName=openwire for consumers?