# How to configure Hermes in SoapUI

Tags: soapui, hermes-jms

Installing SoapUI 5.7.0 in Windows 11 (in Ubuntu the same) I checked Hermes to be installed.
But I don't see HermesJMS option in Tools menu.
Pointing Preferences->Tools->Hermes JMS to SmartBear\SoapUI-5.7.0\hermesJMS does not solve the problem

Could you provided detail steps how to install Hermes with SoapUI?

Comment: In SoapUI 5.2.1 HermesJMS in available in Tools menu right after installation. In instalation wizard it is even checked to be included by default

Comment: HermesJMS was abandoned sometime in 2013 https://sourceforge.net/projects/hermesjms/ It is very difficult to get all the outdated tools you need (Java 6) to get it working again.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried installing SoapUI because I noticed that Hermes was an option on install. I know Hermes is an abandoned project but that product was so good for JMS testing that I was hoping that someone had picked it up. Sadly it seems that SmartBear are no longer supporting it as it says on this page https://www.soapui.org/docs/jms/getting-started/ "Important: SoapUI 5.6 or later does not support HermesJMS."

Curiously though it is still an installable option, but the lib versions seem to be all from 2010 whereas the 'latest' were from 2011 -> https://sourceforge.net/projects/hermesjms/files/hermesjms/1.14/ . Even the later/last version needs a couple of jars upgraded to make it work with JDK 1.8 (xml-apis.jar and xercesImpl.jar). Apart from the clear statement that its no longer supported, the version of hermes that ships with SoapUI may not work with later versions of AMQ such as 5.14.5 as you will hit this problem [Accessing Apache ActiveMQ via JMX throws Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837853/accessing-apache-activemq-via-jmx-throws-exception) .

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question but maybe you could have a look at [JMSToolBox](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox)

JMSToolBox has varioud features for integration testing (Scripts, variables, message templates etc)

It also exposes a REST interface if you want to use it with SoapUI

[Documentation here](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/wiki)
[Download here](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/releases)

(I'm the author of JMSToolBox)